# OpenMP Reference type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, openmp

I have what is follow:

```
#pragma omp parallel reduction( + : sum)
for(int i=0;i<640;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<480;j++)
    {
sum= sum + Mat.at(i,j);
...
```

The problem is that an error message is showed up:

```
variable in 'reduction' clause/directive cannot have reference type
```

I have looked at the website of Microsoft for the OpenMP but it doesn't deal with this problem.

Comment: A simple [search in google](https://www.google.it/search?q=visual+studio+variable+in+'reduction'+clause%2Fdirective+cannot+have+reference+type&oq=visual+studio+variable+in+'reduction'+clause%2Fdirective+cannot+have+reference+type&aqs=chrome.0.57.2770j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) shows [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zh6z181(v=vs.90).aspx) as a first result. If you read the paragraph you will notice that `A variable specified in a private clause must not have an incomplete type or a reference type`. So the problem, most likely, is that `sum` is of reference type.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Variable "sum" should not be a reference, as explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e0et560(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: The link you posted is fine, but the explanation you give is completely wrong. Please, check the examples in the link better and fix your answer.